# SEGMENTATION FAULT (11) for one of my 2d arrays?

Tags: c, arrays, types, malloc

I have 2x 2D arrays as a pointer.
one is "int ** field" and the other one "char **mask".
I want to create 2 2D arrays and initialise them.
The code I have works for the int array but not for the char array, although the code is the same... why?

```
Minesweeper * createField(int n, int m){

    Minesweeper *ms = (Minesweeper *) malloc(sizeof(Minesweeper *));

    ms->m = m;
    ms->n = n;

    ms->field = (int **) malloc(sizeof(int *) * n); 
    ms->mask  = (char **) malloc(sizeof(char *) * n);
    for(int i=0; i<n; i++){
        ms->field[i] = (int *) malloc(sizeof(int *) * m);
        ms->mask[i] = (char *) malloc(sizeof(char *) * m);
    }


    for(int k=0; k<n; k++){
        for(int j=0; j<m; j++){
            ms->field[k][j] = 0;
            ms->mask[k][j] = 'x';
        }
    }

    return ms;
}
```

By the way:

Minesweeper is a typedef struct with 4 attributes: int** field, char** mask, int m and int n.

I always get Segmentation fault when I want to initialize my mask array...

Answer (score 2):

Be careful when you allocate like

```
malloc(sizeof(Minesweeper *));
```

you get memory for a single pointer allocated - `(Minesweeper *)`. To allocate memory for the whole structure you have to use `sizeof(Minesweeper)` - without the asterisk.

So replace with:

```
Minesweeper *ms = (Minesweeper *) malloc(sizeof(Minesweeper));
```

and

```
ms->field[i] = (int *) malloc(sizeof(int) * m);
ms->mask[i] = (char *) malloc(sizeof(char) * m);
```

Comment: If you generally cast the result of malloc to the pointer of the type provided in the sizeof() argument, then the compiler will show you quite reliably if the type you allocated for matches the type, which you assign to. Those warnings can save you from having a hard time debugging.

Comment: @Ctx But when you forget to include the `stdlib.h` header, then the cast will hide the error: `malloc()` will be implicitly declared to return an `int`, leading to UB right away. You only ever need these casts when you try to compile C code with a C++ compiler. So, when you are programming C, better use this `Foo* foo = malloc(sizeof(*foo));`, it avoids any possibility of a type mismatch.

Comment: @cmaster Most compilers will warn anyway: `warning: incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function ‘malloc’`, or `warning: implicit declaration of function ‘malloc’`, if you disable the builtins, so this is a non-issue

Comment: @Ctx Still, the issue remains that the cast is pure noise in C.

Comment: @cmaster Everything that helps improving code-readability and avoiding errors is more than "pure noise". That's like generally calling comments in the code "noise". See the malloc casts as code comments, which additionally help the compiler emit warnings if the programmer does something he didn't intend to do

Comment: @Ctx The casts only repeat the exact same information that is already found in the type of the pointer variable that you assign. Before that assignment, the memory is just that, an untyped slab of uninitialized memory with a specific length. As such, the crucial part is not to cast to the correct type, but to use the correct length in the `malloc()` argument. You are approaching this from a pure C++ mindset: You think in analogy to `new` which produces a fully initialized object, on which a constructor has run. That analogy is false, *`malloc()` really just returns the memory, not an object.*

Comment: @cmaster That's what I tried to explain: redundancy is at the very heart of error detection and correction. Starting with our human language up to data structures, code, redundancy is everywhere. After complex dereferences in pointers and structures it is sometimes hard to comprehend for which kind of object data is allocated. That's where a cast helps twice: comprehending the code and avoiding errors. A comment would just help for task one. So it is clear, what to prefer. Oh, unless you are a dogmatic "casts are evil for malloc"-zealot, of course ;)

Comment: @Ctx I don't know, how religious you perceive me, I try not to be... Anyway, I really have trouble to follow your argumentation: Whenever I code, I try to code everything exactly once. If I need something several times, I'm likely to just give it a descriptive name, and reuse that name. What I definitely do not do is to add redundancy for the sake of redundancy. Never. In my eyes, that just increases the amount of code that I need to parse, and that may contain errors. I'd call that both a violation of DRY and KISS. When I write `int x = foo();`, I don't add a cast either, do I?

Comment: @cmaster I never said, that you should _always_ add a cast, correct? And in this case, the function prototype of foo() gives the necessary information, which is why your comparison doesn't hold here. And: redundancy doesn't mean "redundant code" here, this is something you clearly misunderstood.

Comment: @Ctx Oh, I forgot to mention that `foo()` returns a short, sorry about that ;-) ... So, the return value is implicitly converted to an `int` in the assignment. Exactly like the return value of `malloc()` is implicitly converted to a `Bar*` in the assignment of `Bar* baz = malloc(sizeof(*baz));`. You see, the two situations are really fully analogous: Both functions return something, that is implicitly converted to something else, which is determined by the type of the variables the result is assigned to. And I would not even dream about adding a cast to either.

Comment: @cmaster And you fully ignore the fact, that the cast would have helped the OP in this case (and many other people in an analogous situation). This is, because pointers/structure combinations are somewhat more complex than other primitive (numeric) datatypes. You think simple, your examples are simple, and you think you can generalize this on all cases, despite you have an example right before your nose. But go on, try talking away this ;)

Answer (score 0):

here is what you can use easily instead of your code :)

```
Minesweeper * createField(int n, int m){

    Minesweeper *ms = (Minesweeper *) malloc(sizeof(Minesweeper));

    ms->m = m;
    ms->n = n;

    ms->field = (int **) malloc(sizeof(int *) * n); 
    ms->mask  = (char **) malloc(sizeof(char *) * n);
    for(int i=0; i<n; i++){
        ms->field[i] = (int *) malloc(sizeof(int ) * m);
        ms->mask[i] = (char *) malloc(sizeof(char) * m);
    }


    for(int k=0; k<n; k++){
        for(int j=0; j<m; j++){
            ms->field[k][j] = 0;
            ms->mask[k][j] = 'x';
        }
    }

     return ms;
}
```

malloc declaration was not correct.
You are declaring a pointer with size of a type then you need to write as `sizeof(<type>)` instead of `sizeof(*<type>)` which will give size of pointer instead of the actual storage. It will solve the error :)